# React hooks: useEffect not being triggered on array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For readability im going to strip out a lot of functionality in my examples. However, essentially I have a `useEffect` (shown below) that has a dependency that tracks the `state.cards` array of card objects. My assumption was that if that `state.cards` property changes then the `useEffect` should trigger. However, that's not exactly proving to be the case.

Below are two solutions that are being used. I *want* to use the first one since it's in constant time. The second, while fine, is linear. What confuses me is why the second option triggers the dependency while the first does not. Both are return a clone of correctly modified state.

This **does not** trigger the useEffect dependency `state.cards`.

```
      const newArr = { ...state };
      const matchingCard = newArr.cards[action.payload];   <-- payload = number
      matchingCard.correct += 1;
      matchingCard.lastPass = true;
      return newArr;
```

This **does** trigger the useEffect dependency `state.cards`.

```
      const newArr = { ...state };
      const cards = newArr.cards.map((card) => {
        if (card.id === action.payload.id) {
          card.correct += 1;
          card.lastPass = true;
        }
        return card;
      });
      return { ...newArr, cards };
```

**useEffect**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const passedCards = state.cards.filter((card) => {
      return card.lastPass;
    });
    setLearnedCards(passedCards);
    const calculatePercent = () => {
      return (learnedCards.length / state.cards.length) * 100;
    };
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_PERCENT_COMPLETE', payload: calculatePercent() });
  }, [learnedCards.length, state.cards]);
```

**State**

```
const initialState = {
  cards: [],  <-- each card will be an object
  percentComplete: 0,
  lessonComplete: false,
};
```

---

---

---

**Solution:** Working solution using the first example:

```
      const newCardsArray = [...state.cards];
      const matchingCard = newCardsArray[action.payload];
      matchingCard.correct += 1;
      matchingCard.lastPass = true;
      return { ...state, cards: newCardsArray };
```

Why: Spreading the array `state.cards` creates a new shallow copy of that array. Then I can make modifications on that cloned array and return it as the new value assigned to `state.cards`. The spread array has a new reference and that is detected by `useEffect`.

Comment: What does `state` looks like?

Comment: @Yousaf updated with the initial state

Comment: Problem in the first code example is that it is modifying the state directly. `{ ...state }` - This won't clone the objects inside the `state`. Meaning you are mutating the `cards` array directly. This doesn't changes the `state.cards`, hence `useEffect` is not triggered. Mapping over the `state.cards` is the way to do it.

Comment: `{ ...state }` - This is making a new object, copying the properties of `state` in the new object but objects are reference types, so you are basically creating a property named `cards` in the new object but its value is the _same_ array reference which was pointed to by `cards` property in `state` object.

Comment: your next problem is that you are using `learnedCards.length` and `state.cards.length` right after setting them, but they will still return the current render's values.

Comment: @yousaf thank you for the help, it made it much more clear.

Comment: @pilchard I believe it this example it's fine. I have another `useEffect` that populates the array on mount. So it's length will be 4 (in this case). The `setLearnedCards` updates a useState hook which evidently is successfully being picked up in the `calculatePercent()` function.

Comment: @Kevin fair enough. I have a feeling it's catching the correct value on rerender. You could simply use `passedCards.length` to pass the correct value in the same useEffect cycle.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks! yeah, that was my initial thought as well but several components need that value and they exist outside of the `useEffect` so I figured I would capture it there, use it, and also send it up to the component state to pass it elsewhere.

Comment: You can still set the value there, but using `passedCards.length` would allow you to simplify your dependency array by removing `learnedCards.length` which may save you a race condition down the line. `useEffect(() => { const passedCards = state.cards.filter((card) => { return card.lastPass; }); setLearnedCards(passedCards); const calculatePercent = () => { return (passedCards.length / state.cards.length) * 100; };  dispatch({ type: 'SET_PERCENT_COMPLETE', payload: calculatePercent() });  }, [state.cards]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My best guess is that in the second working example .map returns a new array with a new reference. In the first example you are just mutating the contents of the array but not the reference to that array.

I am not exactly sure how useEffect compares, but if I remember correctly for an object it is just all about the reference to that object. Which sometimes makes it difficult to use useEffect on objects. It might be the same with arrays too.

Why dont you try out:

```
const newCardsArray = [...state.cards]
// do your mutations here
```

should copy the array with a new ref like you did with the object.

Comment: 'keys' in the array? Your comment doesnt make a lot of sense or I am missing details to help you.
If you want to force an update update the reference of you pass along as a prop to another component. The above example does it for arrays